# Variable derives itself

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, derivation

In Sipser's Introduction to the theory of computation (3rd edition), I found the following claim.

Consider the grammar:

$$
\begin{align*}
&R \to XRX \mid S \\
&S \to aTb \mid bTa \\
&T \to XTX \mid X \mid \epsilon \\
&X \to a \mid b
\end{align*}
$$

In this grammar, it holds that $T \Rightarrow^* T$.

Can anyone explain how this is true?

Answer (score 2):

We say that $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \beta$ if $\beta$ can be derived from $\alpha$ in zero or more steps. (More fancily, $\Rightarrow^*$ is the reflexive-transitive closure of $\Rightarrow$.) In particular, it is always that case that $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \alpha$, for every $\alpha$, due to a derivation of zero steps.

In contrast, in your case it doesn't hold that $T \Rightarrow^+ T$. (This is derivation in one or more steps, or the transitive closure of $\Rightarrow$.)